# JQuery Cycle Function

Tags: jquery, slider

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle

```
$('#slides').cycle({
            fx:    'fade', 
            sync:   0, 
            delay: -5000 
});
```

I want it so my slides fade in, wait 5 seconds then fade out to the next slide - I've been trying for a while but to no avail - any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#slides').cycle({
            // The 'fade' fx it's the default transition of Cycle
            timeout: 5000, // Between every transition
            delay: 5000 // Before first transition
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#slides').cycle({
    fx:    'fade', 
    sync:   0, 
    timeout: 5000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The option for delays between slides is

```
timeout
```

So you should use:

```
$('#slides').cycle({
        fx:    'fade', 
        sync:   0, 
        timeout: 5000 
});
```